# Flutter Web Image Picker and Uploading Image to Firebase

Tags: flutter, cloud-storage

Flutter 2 announced just few days ago and some packages updated for web like Image Picker. I'm trying to get image and upload it to cloud storage. Image picker working very well but when

I want to upload image to storage it gives me error.

```
Unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem
```

UI Code

```
onImageSelect: (selectedImage) async {
                        try {
                          final url = await Get.find<FirebaseStorageService>()
                              .uploadProfilePicture(
                                  customer.uuid, File(selectedImage.path));
                          print(url);
                        } catch (e) {
                          print(e);
                        }
                        customer.profileImageUrl = selectedImage.path;
                        _isImageSelected = true;
                      }),
```

Service Class funciton:

```
class FirebaseStorageService {
  final FirebaseStorage _firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
  Reference _storageReference;

  Future<String> uploadProfilePicture(
      String userID, File uploadingImagePath) async {
    _storageReference = _firebaseStorage
        .ref()
        .child(userID)
        .child('images')
        .child("profile-photo.png");
    var uploadTask = _storageReference.putFile(uploadingImagePath);
    var url = await (await uploadTask).ref.getDownloadURL();

    return url;
  }
}
```

I tried flutter clean and flutter upgrade. I also searched old questions and some of them used html.File instead of dart:io library but firebase_storage:7.0.0 package only accept File class which is from dart:io library.
Code work on Android and IOS but not web.

I'm using stable channel.

Comment: I changed _storageReference.putFile(uploadingImage) to  _storageReference.putFile( await uploadingImage.readAsBytes()) and it give another error: 
Unsupported operation: _Namespace

Comment: did u manage to solve the _Namespace error?

Comment: @niklodeon no, I did not use flutter to build web project.